# SQL Time Series Homework

Tags: sql

Imagine you have this two tables.

a) streamers: it contains time series data, at a 1-min granularity, of all the channels that broadcast on
Twitch. The columns of the table are:

- username: Channel username
- timestamp: Epoch timestamp, in seconds, corresponding to the moment the data was captured
- game: Name of the game that the user was playing at that time
- viewers: Number of concurrent viewers that the user had at that time
- followers: Number of total followers that the channel had at that time

b) games_metadata: it contains information of all the games that have ever been broadcasted on Twitch.
The columns of the table are:

- game: Name of the game
- release_date: Timestamp, in seconds, corresponding to the date when the game was released
- publisher: Publisher of the game
- genre: Genre of the game

Now I want the Top 10 publishers that have been watched the most during the first quarter of 2019. The output should contain publisher and hours_watched.

The problem is I don't have any database, I created one and inputted some values by hand.

I thought of this query, but I'm not sure if it is what I want. It may be right (I don't feel like it is ), but I'd like a second opinion

```sql
    SELECT publisher, 
        (cast(strftime('%m', "timestamp") as integer) + 2) / 3 as quarter, 
        COUNT((strftime('%M',`timestamp`)/(60*1.0)) * viewers) as total_hours_watch
    FROM streamers AS A INNER JOIN games_metadata AS B ON A.game = B.game 
    WHERE quarter = 3
    GROUP BY publisher,quarter 
    ORDER BY total_hours_watch DESC
```

Comment: What Happens When You Run It? (tm) The argument of "I don't have a database" is bogus. Go build your database (on dbfiddle.uk, sqlfiddle.com, or wherever) and test your query. Then you'll **KNOW** if it works or not.

Comment: I have a database, it doesn't return an error, I was just looking for a second opinion, I know it works, I just don't know if it's actually giving me the right output, as I am having trouble with the question itself, specially with the hours_watch concept and the fact that it is a timer series!I expressed myself not in the best way tho!

Comment: Are you sure the time math is right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks about right to me. You don't need to include quarter in the `GROUP BY` since the where clause limits you to only one quarter. You can modify the query to get only the top 10 publishers in a couple of ways depending on the SQL server you've created.

For SQL Server / MS Access modify your select statement: `SELECT TOP 10 publisher, ...`
For MySQL add a limit clause at the end of your query: `... LIMIT 10;`